# Android Support Library: Retained Fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I'm experiencing a possibly strange behavior with a retained fragment. This is my situation:
I've a retained fragment that when a configuration change occurs in its hosting Activity is not recreated (i.e., its onCreate method is not invoked) as I would expect. The strange thing is the following: if the hosting Activity is recreated due to memory pressure (you can force this by opening many other apps depending on the RAM available on your device) it receives bundle != null in its onCreate and the *onCreate method of the retained fragment is called too*. This seems very strange to me given it is a retained fragment. Where can I find the docs related to this behavior?

If you would like to reproduce this behavior you can try with the support library sample "Retain Instance" declared in "FragmentRetainInstanceSupport.java"

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> if the hosting Activity is recreated due to memory pressure (you can
>   force this by opening many other apps depending on the RAM available
>   on your device) it receives bundle != null in its onCreate and the
>   onCreate method of the retained fragment is called too

Well if there is a memory problem which resulted in the `Activity` being killed I wouldn't have high hopes for the `Fragment`. If the app is killed, then nothing survives. You cannot escape the lifecycle. You may be able to reduce the chances of a `Fragment` or `Activity` being recreated, but you cannot prevent it.

You have to program your app with that in mind. Everything may be killed at any moment, your app needs to survive that without any exceptions and you cannot depend on something not being recreated or killed.